# Mat-select with the option to type

Tags: angular

I had an input on the site of this mat-select, but now I need it to be able to select something that comes from the database, or type.
But I can only make him select, how can I make him also type within the mat-select ?

```
 <mat-select id="name" name="name" required [(ngModel)]="activity.name">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let composition of filteredCompositions" [value]="composition.name">
            {{ composition.name  }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use another component like mat-autocomplete, this will allow you have a list of suggestions and also a input to type. For more info visit https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Comment: @EliezerVerasVargas Thank you, it worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, I suggest you to use another component like `mat-autocomplete`, which allows you to have a list of options and also a input to type.

> The autocomplete is a normal text input enhanced by a panel of suggested options.

Fore more info, visit https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Note: I gave this answer in the comments but I wanted to make it more visible so also added to the answers section.